# Update ListItem from Client Objectmodel without changing the version

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

Is it possible to update the Created/Modified fields using the Sharepoint Client ObjectModel without updating the version?

```
var file = _ClientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
_ClientContext.Load(file);
_ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
ListItem listItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
listItem["Created"] = info.SourceFile.CreationTime;
listItem["Modified"] = info.SourceFile.LastWriteTime;
MapMembers(listItem, info.MetaData);
listItem.Update();
```

listItem.SystemUpdate / Update(false) is not available in the Client ObjectModel.

Thanks

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem here and I'd really much like to know if there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 7):

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File lp_newFile = lp_web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(lp_uri.LocalPath);
lp_context.Load(lp_newFile);
lp_context.ExecuteQuery();

//check out to make sure not to create multiple versions
lp_newFile.CheckOut();

ListItem lp_item = lp_newFile.ListItemAllFields;
listItem["Created"] = info.SourceFile.CreationTime;
listItem["Modified"] = info.SourceFile.LastWriteTime;
listItem.Update();

// use OverwriteCheckIn type to make sure not to create multiple versions 
lp_newFile.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
```